# System.IO.Pipelines Length Field Based TCP Decoding

Tags: c#, tcp, .net-core

I'm attempting to port code from DotNetty to System.IO.Pipelines. In DotNetty I'm leveraging the LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder to decode a TCP message where the first two bytes represent an integer indicating the length of the entire message.

All the demos I've seen rely on string based EOL indicators. i feel this should be easy but it's escaping me how to grab the first two bytes, and then X amount of bytes, as indicated by the length prefix.

Below is an example taken from David Fowler's [TcpEcho server](https://github.com/davidfowl/TcpEcho). How can I rewrite this to parse the message if the first two bytes indicated the message size rather than an EOL character indicating the end of messsage?

```
 private static async Task ReadPipeAsync(Socket socket, PipeReader reader)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            ReadResult result = await reader.ReadAsync();

            ReadOnlySequence<byte> buffer = result.Buffer;
            SequencePosition? position = null;

            do
            {
                // Find the EOL
                position = buffer.PositionOf((byte)'\n');

                if (position != null)
                {
                    var line = buffer.Slice(0, position.Value);
                    ProcessLine(socket, line);

                    // This is equivalent to position + 1
                    var next = buffer.GetPosition(1, position.Value);

                    // Skip what we've already processed including \n
                    buffer = buffer.Slice(next);
                }
            }
            while (position != null);

            // We sliced the buffer until no more data could be processed
            // Tell the PipeReader how much we consumed and how much we left to process
            reader.AdvanceTo(buffer.Start, buffer.End);

            if (result.IsCompleted)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        reader.Complete();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/StephenClearyExamples/TcpEcho) is what I ended up with:

```
private const int lengthPrefixSize = 2; // number of bytes in the length prefix
private static ushort ParseLengthPrefix(ReadOnlySpan<byte> buffer) => BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt16LittleEndian(buffer);

private static ushort ParseLengthPrefix(in ReadOnlySequence<byte> buffer)
{
    if (buffer.First.Length >= lengthPrefixSize)
        return ParseLengthPrefix(buffer.First.Span.Slice(0, lengthPrefixSize));

    Span<byte> lengthPrefixBytes = stackalloc byte[lengthPrefixSize];
    buffer.Slice(0, lengthPrefixSize).CopyTo(lengthPrefixBytes);
    return ParseLengthPrefix(lengthPrefixBytes);
}

private static async Task ReadPipeAsync(Socket socket, PipeReader reader)
{
    ushort? lengthPrefix = null;

    while (true)
    {
        ReadResult result = await reader.ReadAsync();

        ReadOnlySequence<byte> buffer = result.Buffer;

        while (true)
        {
            if (lengthPrefix == null)
            {
                // If we don't have enough for the length prefix, then wait for more data.
                if (buffer.Length < lengthPrefixSize)
                    break;

                // Read and parse the length prefix
                lengthPrefix = ParseLengthPrefix(buffer);
                buffer = buffer.Slice(lengthPrefixSize);
            }

            // If we haven't read the entire packet yet, then wait.
            if (buffer.Length < lengthPrefix.Value)
                break;

            // Read the data packet
            var line = buffer.Slice(0, lengthPrefix.Value);
            ProcessLine(socket, line);

            buffer = buffer.Slice(lengthPrefix.Value);
            lengthPrefix = null;
        }

        // We sliced the buffer until no more data could be processed
        // Tell the PipeReader how much we consumed and how much we left to process
        reader.AdvanceTo(buffer.Start, buffer.End);

        if (result.IsCompleted)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    reader.Complete();
}
```

This solution does have a length prefix buffer, but it's only used if the length prefix is split across spans. There is a [`SequenceReader<T>` coming](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/32588) that I think can make this totally copy-less, though in the case of length prefixes (very few bytes and no buffer allocations), the difference would probably be minimal.

Comment: Buffer copies! Here's how GRPC does it https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/blob/6504c26be7ff763f6367daf1a43b8c01eefc3e7a/src/Grpc.AspNetCore.Server/Internal/PipeExtensions.cs#L158-L184

Comment: SequenceReader<T> has been added as per Stephen's comments.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.sequencereader-1?view=net-5.0